# How can one tell if a sequence is well-defined; is the axiom of choice needed?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This question is in the context of the following exercise:
Let $X$ be a first countable topological space, let $A \subseteq X$, and let $x \in X$ with $x \in \overline{A}$. Then there exists a sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq A$ with $a_{n} \rightarrow x$.

**My work:**

Let $\{U_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable nbhd base for $x$. Consider the sequence $\{\cap_{i=1}^{n}U_{i}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Each $\cap_{i=1}^{n}U_{i}$ contains an element of $A$. Call this element $a_{n}$. Then $a_{n} \rightarrow x$ because if $\mathcal{O}$ is an open nbhd of x, there's some $j$ such that $U_{j} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$. Then $a_{n} \in \cap_{i=1}^{n}U_{i} \subseteq \cap_{i=1}^{j}U_{i} \in \mathcal{O}$ for all $n \geq j$. My question is: is it o.k. to form a sequence in that way? Do we get the information of what the points $a_{n}$ are all at once? (in which case we have tangible objects with which we form our sequence) The axiom of choice wouldn't be needed, would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the axiom of choice needed. In fact the axiom of countable choice is equivalent to this exercise (it is equivalent in the case of metric spaces, which are first-countable).

The reason is that you chose $a_n$ from each set in the sequence. This means that you made infinitely many choices, but you haven't (and weren't) supplied with a uniform way of making them. Therefore the axiom of choice was invoked.

There is indeed a counterexample where the axiom of choice fails and there is a metric space which has a closure point which no sequence can reach.

Other than that, the proof seems fine.

Comment: Thanks @Asaf. I had no idea the axiom of choice has its own tag. :D

Comment: Does the counterexample mean that the exercise is false?

Comment: Without the axiom of choice? It is *consistent* that it is false.